# number´s of parse strings from xml

Tags: java, android, xml, arrays, string

i have a little question :).My problem is , that i parse a xml and make by every tag there are parsing a new fragment. .But now my problem:
By creating Tabs i must give the `FragmentPagerAdapter` the numbers of tabs there he must creating.I downt know why i can give him they without array list.Thats the code there say how much tabs he must creating.Normaly it locks like
public final String[] titles = {"123", "123"}; but now i parse it to a string without array.

```
@Override
        public int getCount() {
            return Names.length();
        }
```

but this isnt posible with Strings, so my question can anybody can tell me a solution on there i can give him a number of the tags from the xml there he have parse.

the xml:

```
<rooms>
<room>
        <roomname>Wohnzimmer</roomname>
        <devices>
            <device>
                <deviceid>1</deviceid>
                <devicename>some name</devicename>
                <action1>3</action1>
                <action2>4</action2>
                <devicetype>some name</devicetype>
                <text1>1</text1>
                <text2>2</text2>
            </device>
        </devices>
    </room>
        <room>
        <roomname>Wohnzimmer</roomname>
        <devices>
            <device>
                <deviceid>1</deviceid>
                <devicename>some name</devicename>
                <action1>3</action1>
                <action2>4</action2>
                <devicetype>some name</devicetype>
                <text1>1</text1>
                <text2>2</text2>
            </device>
        </devices>
    </room>
</rooms>
```

i need the childs there are the xml parser parse from the category rooms(the childs from the tag rooms).i want to count the tags there the rooms tag have. in this case its are 2.

My code looks now so:

```
@Override
        public int getCount() {
            try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document dom = db.parse("employees.xml");
            Element element = (Element) dom.getElementsByTagName("app_type").item(0);
            NodeList nodes = dom.getElementsByTagName("tagName");
            int count = nodes.getLength();      
        }
        catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SAXException sae) {
        sae.printStackTrace();
        }
            return count;
        }
```

but i get a error on count he cant resolve count.

Comment: you should explain your problem a little bit better, i read this 3 times and still didn't get the exact issue.

Comment: also show more code and the xml that you're parsing

Comment: i want to count the tags there are inside the rooms in this case its are 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood you have an xml and you are looking to parse few tags out of that xml, you can use XML java API

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document dom = db.parse("employees.xml");
Element element = (Element) dom.getElementsByTagName("app_type").item(0);
NodeList nodes = dom.getElementsByTagName('"tagName");
int count = nodes.getLength();
```

Dont forget to put this in try catch block as this API throws exceptions.

Cheers !!

Comment: i want to count the tags there the rooms tag have

Comment: @johanfra - Not sure if I understood but made an attempt, see edit have added anotherline to get count of a particular tagName

Comment: @johanfra.. Wonderful !!